# window.history.pushState not working

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have this website http://www.testplaats6.be with a audioplayer that keeps on playing when clicking through the site. But i have some issues.

I've used this demo to start upon:
http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/06/history-api/

So i have the index.php and the index.php in the 'pages' folder.
When loading the index.php for the first time (and start the music), i can click on the content while hearing the music. Nice. But when going back to the homepagina via the navigation or back key; then the music stops when clicking on that same content.

How could this be ?
For the content blocks in the main navigation i have no problem; the music keeps on playing. But not for the content part.

This is the javascript i use in the header; under history.js.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function anchorClick(link) {
        var linkSplit = link.split('/').pop();
        $.get('pages/' + linkSplit, function (data) {
            $('#wrapper').html(data);
        });
    }
    $('.goto').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        anchorClick($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
        anchorClick(location.pathname);
    });
});
```

Strange thing is. When i also use the same javascript also in the php-files under the folder 'pages'; it works but while browser throught the site; the pages starts to flikker because of multiple loading i guess.

Can somebody help me out; thanks.

Comment: As far as I know your `anchorClick` function is in the `$(document).ready()` scope and so can't be called outside of it, unless you declare it globally. (Correct me if I'm wrong) Did you try to put everything in the same scope? Or declare `var anchorClick;` outside of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks for answering. I'm a step further; i just added the class 'goto' to the div id wrapper. And now i can click in the content AND the music keeps on playing. But that brings out another 'problem', on the label-page i have a lightbox on the pictures (also a A-href); then i get a wrong url as it points to the images.

Comment: Quentin did edit your post, not answer ;) There are several ways to solve the new problem. Add a class like `dontPush` or something and then check for it. `if ( $(this).hasClass('dontPush') ) return;`